# InnerHTML onclick doesn't recognize a function

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a javascript file in which I am adding innerHTML to change a div and the onclick tells me that the function is undefined. In my case the function test() is not recognized. Any suggestions?
Here is the code:

```
this.initialize = function(){

    var startInput =(document.getElementById('startInput'));

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<img id="cur_location_img" style="position:absolute;z-index: 1; margin-top: 7px; left:330px; top:20px;"'+
    ' src="../images/location.png" onclick="test()"/>';
    startInput.appendChild(div)
}

function test(){
    console.log("IN TEST");
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is `this` in that code, it should be the `window`

Comment: To quicly test, you could do `window.test = function() { ...` and it will probably work, showing you that your function is out of the global scope

Comment: thanks a lot, there was a scope problem, it worked with window.test=function(){...}

Comment: That means you should generally move your `test` function to the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

please use `windows.funcname` to run.

```
function initialize() {

    var startInput =(document.getElementById('startInput'));

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<img id="cur_location_img" style="position:absolute;z-index: 1; margin-top: 7px; left:330px; top:20px;"'+
    ' src="../images/location.png" onclick="window.ttt()"/>';
    startInput.appendChild(div)
}

window.ttt = function () {
    alert('done');
}

initialize();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/xk9jky6h/)